# Why won't my text file save it's changes when I try to delete a line from it?

Tags: c#, file-io

Just making a simple "fish finder" console app for a project. Saves info on fish you've caught and then retrieves info for you based on what kind of fish you're looking for and how to catch it. Here's the primary problem: I've added the functionality for the user to to delete previously recorded catches. When you delete one, the program itself will recognize that in memory and as far as you can see, it appears that it has been deleted. However, once you close the program and either read the actual CSV file or start the program back up, that deleted catch will still be there. There seems to be something wrong with my logic in the process of writing to the file. Note: I always make sure the file is closed when I'm running the program to help prevent corruption/glitching.

I have a Journal class which contains a List called Catches that stores all the catches a user has recorded. This is Journal's method that prompts a user when they want to delete a catch. It lists all the user's recorded catches and then the deleting logic is in the last few lines.

```
    public void DeleteACatch()
    {
        int i = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("**** Delete a Catch ****");
        foreach(var ctch in catches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} - {ctch.ToStringFormatted()}");
            i++;
        }
        Console.Write("Enter number of catch to delete (0 to cancel): ");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(choice == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu...");
            return;
        }
        Catches.RemoveAt(choice - 1);
        Send();
        storageManager.Write();
        Console.WriteLine("Catch deleted.");
    }
```

This is Journal's send method. Simply sends the data to an object of a class called StorageManager, which holds a List called data, which also holds Catches.

```
    public void Send()
    {
        storageManager.Data.Clear();
        storageManager.Data = catches;
    }
```

This is StorageManager's Write method, which takes the Catches stored in it's List called data, and then overwrites the CSV file with it.

```
    public void Write()
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("FishFinderData.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            fileWriter.WriteLine($"{d.HourOfDay},{d.Location},{d.Species},{d.Bait}");
        }
        fileWriter?.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Debug your program. Is your Write method actually called? Don't just assume/believe it does, verify with the debugger (set a breakpoint to confirm the method is actually being called). Then, if you confirmed it is being called, what is the actual and precise content of `data`? Again, don't assume/believe that it will just contain the _right_ data, use the debugger to inspect the content of the `data` field. Third, pay utmost attention to the naming of your fields/properties/etc. `data` is not the same as `Data`. It seems to me you have a field `data` and then you have another field `Data`.

Comment: (Side note: Use the `using` statement with your StreamReader instead of manually closing it. It's an `IDisposable`, and using the `using` statement makes sure the StreamWriter will be closed in a timely fashion even in a case where something in your Write method would throw an exception. Since the StreamWriter takes ownership of the FileStream, using the `using` statement would strictly not be necessary in this particular situation here...)

Comment: By the way, not only have you discrepancies in your code with regard to `data` vs. `Data`, but also with `catches` vs. `Catches`, which might perhaps be related to your problem (or might not; we don't really know how any of `data`, `Data`, `catches` and `Catches` are declared, so we can't say either way...). C# language is a case-sensitive language...

Comment: As a final note, i just noticed that you use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` there for your file stream. Note that this particular FileMode would not delete the old/original content of an existing file. Thus, if the existing file has _for example_ the following text lines like Line1 Line2 Line3, and you would then read the file into a collection and delete the last line from the collection (now you have Line1 Line2 in memory), and then finally write Line1 and Line2 back to the file, the file would remain virtually unchanged, because Line3 in the file would remain untouched/not overwritten. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) More specifically, if you write less content to the file then it already contains when using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, any original/old content of the file not being overwritten by newly written data will remain in the file. To avoid this possible scenario, choose a different FileMode that will ensure the old content of the file is eliminated before writing the new content to the file (the documentation for `System.IO.FileMode` should help you in selecting a more fitting FileMode in that case)